# Как открыть PDF документ на форме Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Нужно открыть документ на форме. Как это сделать?

Comment: TOLEContainer + F1

Answer (score 2):

Стандартными средствами никак, или писать самому или воспользоваться готовыми компонентами. Для примера можете почитать [эту](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2013/06/obzor-5-reshenij-dlya-sozdaniya-i-raboty-s-pdf-v-delphi/) статью. Там описаны примеры работы с такими компонентами, как:

- Synopse PDF Engine
- PowerPDF
- HotPDF
- PDF Creator Pilot
- PDFtoolkit VCL

первые два бесплатные. Существуют и другие компоненты, погуглить, думаю, труда не составит.
Например [TPrintPDF](http://decoding.dax.ru/download/component/pdf/pdf.html)